# regex to match a series of single Character followed by a single space

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to use python regex to match a series of single Character followed by a single space

Example: "My name is arun its A R U N jayapal. I am going to London."

Here, the regex should match only "A R U N " and not match "I ". Please help. Currently I am using the following regex, which matches only A U I.

(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9]\s)+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match at least *2* character-space combos, but preceded by a word boundary (to ensure your first character is not the end of a word):

```
\b(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]\s){2,}
```

This matches `A R U N` and not `I`:

```
>>> re.search(r'\b(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]\s){2,}', 'My name is arun its A R U N jayapal. I am going to London.').group()
'A R U N '
```